# a question on database seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have the following code defined inside db/seeds.rb,

```
default_car=Car.create({:name=>'TOYOTA'})
User.create({:username=>'default_user', car_id=>default_car.id})
```

I know the `default_car` and the `user` instances will be stored into Database when I run "**rake db:seed**".

My question is, if I run '**rake db:seed**' **again, again and again**(multiple times), will the same instances be stored to database with multiple copies or it only save the instance once into database no matter how many times I run **rake db:seed**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

depends on your models if you allow duplicate values. if you don't it will throw an error. what you do is to clear your db first before running seed via rake db:resetdb

Comment: I see, can I define one rake task with "db:reset" run first and "db:seed" run following?

Comment: yeah actually it was rake db:resetdb. it rollbacks and migrates the whole db again. then that's when you call rake db:seed

Comment: Rather than assuming a development environment, we should always assume a production environment since silly mistakes get made otherwise. And what you're suggesting will be catastrophic in production.

Answer (score 5):

Better solution:

```
default_car = Car.find_or_create_by_name 'TOYOTA'
user = User.find_or_create_by_username 'default_user'
user.car = default_car
user.save
```

That way you can run "rake db:seed" multiple times without having to drop the database manually every time.

Comment: I'd call this the RIGHT answer rather than the better one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of having a single seed file. I was finding this frustrating as the application grows you often want to add new seed data so you end up either doing what Pascal suggests or creating either migrations with data in them or rake tasks to load the seeds. To get round this I knocked up [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank). So I combine this with Pascals approach so I can re-run the seeds but can also target specific ones if I want to.